# Laravel views MIME type issues

Tags: laravel, mime-types

While loading a view all assets are wrongly transferred with a MIME type `text/html`

So on the console I see:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://trivia.dev/guest". guest:11
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://trivia.dev/guest". guest:71
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The syntax error is on the first line of the html file, which means that it is read as a script, instead of HTML. For some reason this only occurs when I am pulling a script in my HTML.

My master layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <title>@yield('title') | Royal Trivia</title>

    <link rel="icon" href="{{URL::to('img/favicon.png')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('css/style.css')}}">
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/bundle.min.js')}}"></script>

</head>
<body>

   <div class="flash">{{Session::get('flash_message')}}</div>
    @yield('content')

  </body>
</html>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <title>שחק וזכה | Royal Trivia</title>

    <link rel="icon" href="http://trivia.dev/img/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://trivia.dev/css/style.css">
    <script src="http://trivia.dev/js/bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

   <div class="flash"></div>

<header>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="lang-icons">
            <li><a href=""><img src="" alt="hebrew"/></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" alt="english"/></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" alt="spanish"/></a></li>
        </ul> <!--lang-icons-->

            <a class="logo" href="/">
                <img src="http://trivia.dev/img/mobile/logo.png" alt="RoyalTrivia"/>
            </a><!--logo-->

        <div class="users-count">
            <small>כרגע באתר 1000 משתמשים</small>
        </div>
    </div><!--container-->

</header><div class="cta-strip">
    <div class="container">
        <img class=mobile src="http://trivia.dev/img/mobile/login_image.png" alt="people"/>
        <div class="cta-text">
    <h1>משחק הטריוויה שמטריף את כולם</h1>
    <h4>הידע שלכם שווה כסף</h4>
    <h5>ענו על 3 שאלות טריוויה</h5>
    <h5>אם עניתם נכון ומהר יותר מהמתחרה מולכם - זכיתם</h5>
    <h3>בואו להרוויח כסף</h3>
</div> <!--cta-text-->    </div> <!--container-->
</div> <!--cta-strip--><div class="buttons-strip">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cta-text">
    <h1>משחק הטריוויה שמטריף את כולם</h1>
    <h4>הידע שלכם שווה כסף</h4>
    <h5>ענו על 3 שאלות טריוויה</h5>
    <h5>אם עניתם נכון ומהר יותר מהמתחרה מולכם - זכיתם</h5>
    <h3>בואו להרוויח כסף</h3>
</div> <!--cta-text-->        <div class="CTA-btns">
            <div class="login-btn clearfix">
                <small>משתמש רשום?</small>
                <a class="star-btn login-link" href="#/login"><span>כניסה</span></a>
            </div><!--login-btn-->

            <div class="signup-btn clearfix">
                <small>לא רשום?</small>
                <a class="star-btn signup-link" href="#/signup"><span>הרשמה</span></a>
            </div><!--signup-btn-->
        </div><!--CTA-btns-->

    </div><!--container-->
</div><!--buttons-strip--><footer>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="social-icons">
            <li><a href='facebook.com'><img src='someimage.png' alt='email'/></a></li>
            <li><a href='facebook.com'><img src='someimage.png' alt=''/></a></li>
            <li><a href='facebook.com'><img src='someimage.png' alt='youtube'/></a></li>
            <li><a href='facebook.com'><img src='someimage.png' alt='google+'/></a></li>
            <li><a href='facebook.com'><img src='someimage.png' alt='twitter'/></a></li>
            <li><a href='facebook.com'><img src='someimage.png' alt='facebook'/></a></li>

        </ul>
        <p>&copy; All rights reserved to Royal Trivia</p>
    </div><!--container-->
</footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the data returned if going to http://trivia.dev/js/bundle.min.js and http://trivia.dev/img/favicon.png from your browser? I'm suspecting it's going to return some Laravel error. Perhaps something to do with your `.htaccess` or file location.

Comment: Good thought. It redirects me to the /guest route. I'm checking my routes.php file now

Comment: It shouldn't reach your Laravel app in the first place, can you show your file structure especially from project folder to your js file? Also your .htaccess if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem thanks to  @Unnawut's advice: The file name was incorrect (should have been bundle.js).
 The weird thing was that I didn't get a 404, but was redirected to the `/guest` route which caused the MIME-type error and the syntax error.

I've looked through my files and found a 404 handler that redirected back to the homepage.

Comment: Can't yet. Only after two days